# Using .htaccess to remove a directory from URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to use .htacess to remove a directory (/category/) from within the generated URL.

The URL looks something like this:

https://domain.com/folder1/folder2/category/folder3/product

I want to remove the /category/ from the URL.

I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
RewriteRule category/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Full .htaccess is as follows:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters. All rights     reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations     listed
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on     Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} OFF
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule category/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

## BEGIN EXPIRES CACHING - OPTIMIZE THE SITE ##
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
## END EXPIRES CACHING - OPTIMIZE THE SITE ##
## BEGIN GZIP COMPRESSION - OPTIMIZE THE SITE ##
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
## END GZIP COMPRESSION - OPTIMIZE THE SITE ##
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|svg)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
   Header unset ETag
   FileETag None
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

The file in the root of the site

Comment: The `^` in your regex means 'at the beginning of the URL'. In your case, the 'category' bit is not at the beginning of the URL - have you tried removing the `^`?

Comment: Thanks, yes just tried that but it's still not working

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located and what are other existing rules?

Answer (score 0):

This rule is fine:

```
RewriteRule category/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But position is wrong. You need to place it just below `RewriteEngine On` line to make it work otherwise Joomla's default front controller rule is making `REQUEST_URI` as `/index.php`.